# Moving control with contraint rather than setting frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, constraints

I've built an app where a UISegmentedControl needs to be moved corresponding to its selected index. I'm using this code to achieve so:

```
- (IBAction)segmentControlAction:(id)sender {
// Change which container will be visible
int selectedIndex = self.overviewSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

if (selectedIndex == 0) {
    // Show details and hide reviews & related

    // SHOW THE DETAILS
    [self showDetails];
} else if (selectedIndex == 1) {
    // Show Reviews and hide details & related

    // SHOW THE REVIEWS
    [self showOther];
} else if (selectedIndex == 2) {
    // Show related and hide details & reviews
}
}

-(void)showOther {
// Animate the reviews
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.9 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
    // Hide details controls
    self.profileImageView.alpha = 0;
    self.seperatorImageView.alpha = 0;
    self.byLabel.alpha = 0;
    self.authorLabel.alpha = 0;

    // Move segmentControl
    [self.overviewSegmentControl setFrame:CGRectMake(self.overviewSegmentControl.frame.origin.x, self.previewImageView.frame.size.height + 8, self.overviewSegmentControl.frame.size.width, self.overviewSegmentControl.frame.size.height)];
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Completed
}];
}

-(void)showDetails{
// Animate the details
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.9 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
    // Move segmentControl
    [self.overviewSegmentControl setFrame:CGRectMake(self.overviewSegmentControl.frame.origin.x, self.previewImageView.frame.size.height + 85, self.overviewSegmentControl.frame.size.width, self.overviewSegmentControl.frame.size.height)];

    // Hide details controls
    self.profileImageView.alpha = 1;
    self.seperatorImageView.alpha = 1;
    self.byLabel.alpha = 1;
    self.authorLabel.alpha = 1;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Completed
}];
}
```

This code moves the UISegmentedControl, but it reverts it to it's original position before performing the actual move. This results in a weird jumping of the control.

My UIViewController:

[image]

Here you can see my constraints:

[image]
[image]

**Can someone please explain me how this works and how to move controls with constraints rather than setting frames?**

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can "set" a constraint to top from your segment controller: "Top space" and modify this constraint accordingly.

Here you have an example [testMovingControll](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/testMovingControll.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can programmaticly modify the ".constant" properties of constraint objects at runtime to set positioning and/or size values.  You do this in the updateConstraints method of your view controller.

You can bind the constraints in your storyboard to properties in your code the same way you bind other objects: control-click-drag from the object into your source code window. Then, you can access them at runtime.

Also, make sure you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to FALSE or you might get conflict constraints.